# While loop taking too much time, can it may be optimized?

Tags: sql-server

I had 80,000 rows in may table , based on that i had to forecast there contribution till their date of retirement, When executing the query it takes around 20 Min to complete. How to optimize the query?

```
declare @Max as int
    declare @Kount as int
        Set @Kount = 1
        SELECT row_number() Over (order by PRAN) as row,
        PRAN, emp_cont, dob, doj_govt, dor,[100 sal],[BP+GP],nps14
        into #rawdata1
        FROM npst
        order by PRAN 

        set @Max = (Select Max(row) from #rawdata1)
        Create Table #Rawdata2
          (
             [Row] int,
            PRAN float,
           emp_cont float,
            dob datetime, 
            doj_govt datetime, 
            dor datetime,
            [100 sal] float,
            [BP+GP] float,
            nps14 float,
            CalAmt float,       
          ) 

        while (@kount <= @max)
        BEGIN
         DECLARE @PRAN float
         SELECT @PRAN  = (PRAN) FROM #rawdata1  where row=@Kount
         DECLARE  @SER_LEFT INT 
         SELECT @SER_LEFT= (DATEDIFF(YEAR,GETDATE(),dor)) from #rawdata1 where row=@Kount
         DECLARE @NPS NUMERIC (10,2)
         SELECT @NPS= nps14 from #rawdata1 where row=@Kount
         DECLARE @I AS INT
         SET @I=1
            WHILE @I<@SER_LEFT
            BEGIN
             SET @NPS=(0.03*@NPS)+@NPS
             SET @I=@I+1
            END
   INSERT INTO #rawdata2
         SELECT @Kount as Row, PRAN, emp_cont, dob, doj_govt, dor,[100 sal],[BP+GP],nps14, @NPS  FROM #rawdata1
           WHERE PRAN=@PRAN
        SET @Kount = @Kount + 1
    END
```

Comment: I'd say yes; get rid of the `WHILE` loop. SQL Server (and other RDBMS) excel at set based operations, not iterative ones. A quick look at your SQL, and it *looks* like this could be achieved with a Set Based Solution. What is your actual goal here? Sample and expect results would be nice (as we can't run your SQL as it stands).

Comment: I'm also surprised that SQL even runs. You're declaring variables like `@PRAN` within your `WHILE`. Thus as soon as the second iteration is entered the statement will fail with an error like `The variable name '@PRAN' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure.`

Comment: @Larnu. Not true, you can declare a variable in a loop, but from personal experience, this creates havoc. When the loop comes around for the second time, it will keep the previous iterations value, if you don't null it out.

Comment: @Happy_Chauhan. Welcome to SO! Could you please give us some example data, to test our answer with?

Comment: You're right @Wyn. I don't like that "feature"...

Comment: if it's too complex to use set based SQL, another option is to use a high level language such as c#.net, which could then consume your initial query as a datareader or a dataset, and would likely be much faster than 20 minutes.

Comment: in terms of set based SQL, you could make your query of #RawData1 a CTE in a WITH statement, and calculate the factors SER_LEFT etc as part of that query, or a 2nd CTE query  -your inner while loop could probably be handled with a scalar function , to which you would pass SER_LEFT and @NPS, then return a calculated value.

Comment: There is absolutely no need for a loop here. But that formatting makes me want to gouge my eyes out. It is a wall of text.

Comment: If you can post the table definition of npst and provide some sample data along with the desired output I would be happy to show you how this can be done set based.

Answer (score -1):

You need to create an index on #Rawdata1 so SQL Server can use seeks instead of scans everytime you look for a row and update a row. I  would create a clustered index first(that is the only way to create an index on a temp table) on the 'row' column and create another index on the 'PRAN' column.

Why is PRAN in parenthesis in the statement?

```
 SELECT @PRAN  = (PRAN) FROM #rawdata1  where row=@Kount
```

Comment: This is not going to help very much. The real issue is using a while loop instead of a set based operation.

Comment: The user insists on using a loop. I am not sure that the calculation can be done within a set based solution. Look at the step: SET @NPS=(0.03*@NPS)+@NPS. In my experience adding a clustered index increases speed by a factor of 10-1000.

Comment: I don't see that the OP has responded to anything. But I am certain this doesn't need to have nested while loops. It absolutely can be done with a tally table pretty easily.

Comment: The only reason to -ever- loop in SQL-Server, is to call a stored proc over and over. Even then, it's probably a bad idea and you should re-look at your problem. Cursoring in SQL is how you lose friends.